# What's the difference

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between, 'Do you have the same thing in other colors?' and 'Do you have the same thing with other patterns?' pleaasseee help me..

Comment: This is a question to which you can easily find the answer by using a dictionary.

Comment: Hard to know exactly what was meant in the second question.  "Pattern" might refer to the arrangement of shapes on the fabric, for example, *sprigged, striped, tie-dye, batik,* etc.  Maybe the person who said that didn't know English thoroughly, and actually meant *a slightly different cut*?

Comment: I mean, it's about the prepositions. Both prepositions can be interchanged like ' Do you have the same thing WITH other colors? ' and ' Do you have the same thing IN other patterns? ' However, I am quite confused about their meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prepositions can be pretty loose here. Color applies to an object and we describe the object as having a color or being of a color. The apple *is red* does not mean it is identical with a color but that its skin appears red.

Designed or built things are made in a color on purpose and this is then a feature or quality of the object. We could say I like the shirt in red but not in blue. Yet the shirt is not inside of the color red or blue. It is just *of* a red or blue color.

The term *With* is also a bit loose here. The shirt is not made *With*, alongside of, red or blue but just with, using, red or blue cloth.

The same applies to *with* other patterns. Think of Do you have this *using*, or *consisting of*, other patterns.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.